# Using mrjob for hadoop streaming: "Error launching job , bad input path : File does not exist:"

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, hdfs

Running this code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mrjob.job import  MRJob

 class MRWordCount(MRJob): 

        def mapper(self, _,line):
                for word in line.split():
                        yield(word,1)

        def reducer(self, word, counts):
                yield(word,sum(counts))

 if __name__ == '__main__':
        MRWordCount.run()
```

The MR job run fails with:

```
        Error launching job , bad input path : File does not exist:    /mnt/hdfs01/hdfs-tmp-dir/hadoop-archmangler/mapred/staging   /archmangler797180279/.staging/job_local797180279_0001/files/mr-job.py#mr-job.py     Streaming Command Failed!
```

- Even though the full directory path up to at least the last component of the path does exist.

Full error dump:

```
 (my_root)archmangler@ec2:~/code/hadoop-streaming$ python mr-job.py -r     hadoop hdfs:///user/archmangler/input.txt 
 No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
 No configs specified for hadoop runner
 Looking for hadoop binary in /usr/local/lol/hadoop/bin...
 Found hadoop binary: /usr/local/lol/hadoop/bin/hadoop
 Using Hadoop version 2.8.2
 Looking for Hadoop streaming jar in /usr/local/lol/hadoop...
 Found Hadoop streaming jar: /usr/local/lol/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools /lib/hadoop-streaming-2.8.2.jar
Creating temp directory /tmp/mr-job.archmangler.20180304.182124.965439
Copying local files to hdfs:///user/archmangler/tmp/mrjob/mr- job.archmangler.20180304.182124.965439/files/...
 Running step 1 of 1...
  session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
  Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
  Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=   - already initialized
   Cleaning up the staging area file:/mnt/hdfs01/hdfs-tmp-dir/hadoop-archmangler/mapred/staging/archmangler797180279/.staging  /job_local797180279_0001
   Error launching job , bad input path : File does not exist:    /mnt/hdfs01/hdfs-tmp-dir/hadoop-archmangler/mapred/staging   /archmangler797180279/.staging/job_local797180279_0001/files/mr-job.py#mr-job.py
 Streaming Command Failed!
 Attempting to fetch counters from logs...
 Can't fetch history log; missing job ID
 No counters found
 Scanning logs for probable cause of failure...
 Can't fetch history log; missing job ID
 Can't fetch task logs; missing application ID
 Step 1 of 1 failed: Command '['/usr/local/lol/hadoop/bin/hadoop', 'jar', '/usr/local/lol/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.8.2.jar', '-files', 'hdfs:///user/archmangler/tmp/mrjob/mr-job.archmangler.20180304.182124.965439/files/mr-job.py#mr-job.py,hdfs:///user/archmangler/tmp/mrjob/mr-job.archmangler.20180304.182124.965439/files/mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip,hdfs:///user/archmangler/tmp/mrjob/mr-job.archmangler.20180304.182124.965439/files/setup-wrapper.sh#setup-wrapper.sh', '-input', 'hdfs:///user/archmangler/input.txt', '-output', 'hdfs:///user/archmangler/tmp/mrjob/mr-  job.archmangler.20180304.182124.965439/output', '-mapper', 'sh -ex setup- wrapper.sh python mr-job.py --step-num=0 --mapper', '-reducer', 'sh -ex   setup-wrapper.sh python mr-job.py --step-num=0 --reducer']' returned non- zero exit status 512
```

However, the path does exist up to at least

```
 /mnt/hdfs01/hdfs-tmp-dir/hadoop-archmangler/mapred/staging/archmangler797180279/.staging/
```

So it appears that for some reason the last parts of the path and the temporary files are not being created?

Questions:

- Is this an issue with the mrjob library?
- How would I troubleshoot this further?

Note: I'm not convinced this is an issue with my hadoop / hdfs site configuration, though I'd be interested if someone knows exactly why this could be the case if they've encountered this issue before.

Many thanks in advance!
Traiano

Comment: Are there spaces after `/.staging` and `/staging` in your error message or did you just copy the error incorrectly?

Comment: @tk421 - no spaces, it seems like copying between screens added a space in there for some reason. Pasted straight from Terminal, this looks as follows:     `Cleaning up the staging area file:/mnt/hdfs1/hdfs-tmp-dir/hadoop-archmangler/mapred/staging/archmangler294861293/.staging/job_local294861293_0001
  Error launching job , bad input path : File does not exist: /mnt/hdfs1/hdfs-tmp-dir/hadoop-archmangler/mapred/staging/archmangler294861293/.staging/job_local294861293_0001/files/mr-job.py#mr-job.py`